# How to fix "No such file or directory" error in setuptools/wheel.py:157 _convert_metadata

Tags: python, setuptools

When running python setup.py test, python setup.py build, or even python setup.py --help-commands I get an "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

So far I've tried upgrading setuptools (currently running version 41.0.1) but this hasn't resolved the issue.

My anonymised setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def read_version():
    with open('version') as ver:
        return ver.read().strip()


config = {
    'description': 'package',
    'author': 'Me',
    'author_email': 'email@email.com',
    'version': read_version(),
    'packages': find_packages(),
    'package_data': {
        'manager.resources': ['*.yaml'],
    },
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'company.packagename',
    'namespace_packages': ['company'],
    'test_suite': 'tests',
    'entry_points': {
        'console_scripts': [
            'launcher = manager_launcher:main',
            'managerschemas = manager.validation:export',
            'managertypes = manager.types:export',
        ]
    },
    'setup_requires': ['pytest-runner'],
    'tests_require': [
        'flake8',
        'pylint',
        'pytest',
        'pytest-cov',
        'pytest-mock',
    ],
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**config)
```

and setup.cfg is:

```
[aliases]
test = pytest

[flake8]
max-line-length = 120
exclude = venv,.eggs

[tool:pytest]
addopts = -vvvv --cov=manager --cov-branch --cov-fail-under=100 --cov-report=term --cov-report=html --junitxml=junit.xml
testpaths = tests
```

The traceback I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    setup(**config)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 717, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 784, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 855, in install_eggs
    return [self.install_wheel(dist_filename, tmpdir)]
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1073, in install_wheel
    os.path.dirname(destination)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 349, in execute
    util.execute(func, args, msg, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/util.py", line 309, in execute
    func(*args)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 101, in install_as_egg
    self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 109, in _install_as_egg
    self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 157, in _convert_metadata
    os.path.join(egg_info, 'PKG-INFO'),
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you show the project directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that this problem was being caused by lag in Vagrant/Virtualbox's synced folders. I was trying to build the Python project inside a Vagrant VM shared from the host file system using a synced folder. Copying the project out of the synced folder into another folder in the VM allows it to build. Another dirty hack that worked was to add a time.sleep(1) in the setuptools/wheel.py source file on line 157 before the os.rename that was causing the OS Exception to be raised. This gives the file system a chance to sync, and therefore works around the issue.